# Is it possible to get on top of the nether in survival mode in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Youtube, I heard many people claiming they did it, but I'm not so sure about it. The top of the Nether is supposed to be surrounded by indestructable bedrock, and getting to there is hard enough. But is it possible to actually reach (not glitch) to the top of the Nether? It would be a really cool view :).

Comment: Have you tried the usual methods from Java edition? Also, how high is the build limit in MCBE? 128 or 256 blocks?

Comment: @FabianRöling He said without glitching, which is impossible.

Comment: @Corsaka No, you can easily get on top of the Nether without bugusing. Just enderpearling onto a block at y=125 (below bedrock at y=127) or using a minecart or boat or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, but they all are technically glitches. The basic methods involve clipping through blocked by use of ender pearls, or hit box collision, to eject you onto the other side of the nether ceiling.

There are many videos explaining how to do it, and some even can explain how to remove the bedrock. None of these are technically cheating however, they are simply exploiting the physics of the game.

Comment: Does exploiting the physics of the game not count as cheating?

Comment: Depends on your definition of the word. OP has stated that they are asking if it's possible to do without clothes, which the answer is no. But in speedruns, duplicating items is an exploit within the game, and is perfectly viable

Comment: Well, it is included in my definition of the term "cheaters".